# React-native: how to use an horizontal scroll view nested inside a native-base Tab component?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, native-base

I'm using Native-base `Tabs` and I'd like to use an horizontal `ScrollView` in one of the tabs.

My code looks like this:

```
<Tabs>
      <Tab
          <MyComponent/>
      </Tab>
      <Tab
          <MyComponent/>
      </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

But the scroll of the child does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work locking the parent tab when the child is scrolling.

There is a snack showing how to it [here](https://snack.expo.io/@nitch7/nested-horizontal-scrollview-inside-tabs-(from-native-base))

Here is the relevant code:

```
<Tabs locked={this.state.isLocked}>
     <Tab
         <MyComponent lockTab={this.lockTab}/>
     </Tab>
     <Tab
         <MyComponent/>
     </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

And inside `MyComponent`:

```
  handleInnerPressIn = () => this.props.lockTab(true);
  handleInnerPressOut = () => this.props.lockTab(false);

<ScrollView nestedScrollEnable={true} horizontal={true}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPressIn={this.handleInnerPressIn}
              onPressOut={this.handleInnerPressOut}>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</SrollView>
```

One **important thing** to note is that it only works if `TouchableWithoutFeedback` is **inside** (and not wrapping) the `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this comment section: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21436

In the end locking scrollviews didn't work like others have suggested, I imported the nested horizontal scrollview from react-native-gesture-handler.